# Display photos and play associated audio with python & cap touch input

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library

I am making what is essentially a "See and Say", but running on a Raspberry Pi. I am using an Adafruit MPR121 capacitive touch sensor to provide the "keyboard" input to control the sequential display of a set of photos, then once the desired photo is displayed, a different "key" is touched to play the associated audio, for example, scroll a list of animal photos, select the duck, then play the sound of a duck quacking.

I am using Adafruit's CircuitPython library for the MPR121 via Blinka, Pillow, and tkinter. I know little to nothing of the last two, but have managed to glom together bits of examples I found online to make something that sort of works to scroll photos.

Based on the time taken to get to that point, I want to ask here if anyone has some suggestions to keep from going down a blind alley, and to see if there is a better way than what I have currently done.

Edits: Changing the delay value of root.after() from 500 to 150 has greatly improved response time - it's long enough to act as a debounce, but not so long that cap touch input is lost.

I got it to work. I'm still poen to suggestions. I left the issues here in case anyone else has similar issues.

I tried using playsound for audio out. I get a warning when it starts:

> playsound is relying on another python subprocess. Please use `pip install pygobject` if you want playsound to run more efficiently.

When I install pygobject, the installer says it is already installed.

When playsound() is called, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/charley/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py", line 261, in <module>
    playsound(argv[1])
  File "/home/charley/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py", line 163, in _playsoundNix
    gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 126, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gst not available
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 814, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "/home/charley/Documents/DogIF/DogIF.py", line 76, in scanTouch
    sound4img()
  File "/home/charley/Documents/DogIF/DogIF.py", line 59, in sound4img
    playsound('/usr/share/scratch/Media/Sounds/Instruments/Dijjeridoo.mp3')
  File "/home/charley/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py", line 254, in <lambda>
    playsound = lambda sound, block = True: _playsoundAnotherPython('/usr/bin/python3', sound, block, macOS = False)
  File "/home/charley/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py", line 229, in _playsoundAnotherPython
    t.join()
  File "/home/charley/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py", line 218, in join
    raise self.exc
  File "/home/charley/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py", line 211, in run
    self.ret = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/charley/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py", line 226, in <lambda>
    t = PropogatingThread(target = lambda: check_call([otherPython, playsoundPath, _handlePathOSX(sound) if macOS else sound]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '/home/charley/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py', '/usr/share/scratch/Media/Sounds/Instruments/Dijjeridoo.mp3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

so I used preferredsoundplayer instead. It works.

Here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

import time
import board
import busio

# Import MPR121 module.
import adafruit_mpr121

from preferredsoundplayer import playsound

# Create I2C bus.
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

# Create MPR121 object.
mpr121 = adafruit_mpr121.MPR121(i2c)

# adjust window
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")

# loading the images
img1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/home/charley/Documents/Components/SBC/RPi/GPIO-Pinout-Diagram-2.png").resize((800,500)))
img2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/home/charley/Pictures/Eastern_Grey_Squirrel.jpg").resize((800,500)))
img3=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/home/charley/Pictures/sqrl.jpg").resize((800,500)))

l=Label(root, text="Apparently not the window title")
l.pack()


x = 1

# function to change to next image
def move(inc):
    global x
    x = x+inc
    if x >= 4:
        x = 1
    if x <= 0:
        x = 3
    if x == 1:
        l.config(image=img1)
    elif x == 2:
        l.config(image=img2)
    elif x == 3:
        l.config(image=img3)
    print("x = {} ".format(x))


def sound4img():
    if x == 1:
        playsound('/usr/share/scratch/Media/Sounds/Instruments/Dijjeridoo.mp3')
    elif x == 2:
        playsound('/usr/share/scratch/Media/Sounds/Instruments/Dijjeridoo.mp3')
    elif x == 3:
        playsound('/usr/share/scratch/Media/Sounds/Instruments/Dijjeridoo.mp3')


# Loop forever testing each input and printing when they're touched.
# while True:
# Loop through all 12 inputs (0-11).
def scanTouch():
    for i in range(12):
        # Call is_touched and pass it the number of the input. If it's touched
        # it will return True, otherwise it will return False.
        if mpr121[i].value:
            print("Input {} touched!".format(i))
            if i == 0:
                move(1)
            if i == 1:
                move(-1)
            if i == 2:
                sound4img()
                
    root.after(150, scanTouch)      # after(delay_ms, callback=None, *args)


root.after(50, scanTouch)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First, I always sugest an OOP aproach when working with tk. This also helps with your `move` function so you can renounce the usage of `global` for `x` and instad make it to a class variable. Secondly in regards to the scaling, I would look into setting a specific size for the label ore even better asign it to the root you created and use the `sticky` parameter: `l=Label(root, sticky="nsew")`
Lastly, maby the response time gets better if you display two buttons instead of constantly scanning for touch input or try a callback function for the root element?

Comment: The finished product will have no keyboard and no mouse, so I'm stuck with scanning the capacitive touch sensor since it is the only input.

Comment: Maby this [documentation on how to use the mpr121 as a keyboard for the raspberry pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-mpr121-12-key-capacitive-touch-sensor-breakout-tutorial/raspberry-pi-virtual-keyboard) is usefull to you. With this you could use a callback on the root element. Not sure if this improves responsetime further but it might do so and seems cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER:** I did not test if the "keyboard" implementation works or if it is more performant

In regards to [this guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-mpr121-12-key-capacitive-touch-sensor-breakout-tutorial/raspberry-pi-virtual-keyboard) the Adafruit MPR121 can be used for keyboard input on the raspberry pi. To do so the following dependencies are necessary:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
sudo pip3 install python-uinput
sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-mpr121
```

After those are installed on your raspberry pi in the MPR121 library examples folder there should be a pi_keyboard.py script with a section of a `KEY_MAPPING` dictionary:

```py
KEY_MAPPING = {
    0: uinput.KEY_UP,
    1: uinput.KEY_DOWN,
    2: uinput.KEY_LEFT,
    3: uinput.KEY_RIGHT,
    4: uinput.KEY_B,
    5: uinput.KEY_A,
    6: uinput.KEY_ENTER,
    7: uinput.KEY_SPACE,
}
```

You could either change this dictionary in a way that it fits your inputs for left right and enter like this (or change the inputs of the sensors to match the dict):

```py
KEY_MAPPING = {
    0: uinput.KEY_RIGHT,  # your right sensor
    1: uinput.KEY_LEFT,  # your left sensor
    2: uinput.KEY_ENTER,  # your "sound" sensor
    3: uinput.KEY_UP,
    4: uinput.KEY_B,
    5: uinput.KEY_A,
    6: uinput.KEY_DOWN,
    7: uinput.KEY_SPACE,
}
```

You then can run this script in the back to use the keybord input in your main script as callback. Do so by running `sudo python keyboard.py &` and note the response ID to later kill the process again with e.g. `sudo kill 2251`.

---

**Now to the main script:**

As we have the key mapping active for your touch sensors we can ommit the part of your script scanning for touches. I tried to make your script more generic, so you can add pictures and sounds and it wil still work. Also this makes it a bit more pythonic I think. Furthermore, I refactored your code into a OOP approach:

```py
from tkinter import *  # if you import everything from tkinter you dont need the as tk line
from PIL import Image, ImageTk  # cleaner to have both imports in one line
from preferredsoundplayer import playsound
from glob import glob  # use this module to get a list of paths


# create App class
class SlidshowApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # instantiate the Tk class of wich you inherit
        # set Window title and geometry
        self.title('Animal Slideshow')  # title is set for the root window, not in a Label text
        self.geometry('800x500')
        # instantiate a empty list to add all the pictures
        self.imagelist = []
        # Load all image paths from your image folder into a list and iterate over it
        for path in glob('/home/charley/Pictures/*.jpg'):
            self.imagelist.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path).resize((800, 500))))
        # also glob all the sound paths (make sure the sounds are in the same order as the pictures!)
        self.soundlist = glob('/usr/share/scratch/Media/Sounds/Instruments/*.mp3')
        # instantiate the Label as a container element for the pictures
        self.img_container = Label(self)
        self.img_container.pack()
        # counter as instance variable
        self.x = 1
        # bind keystrokes (your sensors) to the root to trigger move or sound4image
        self.bind('<Left>', lambda event: self.move(inc=-1))
        self.bind('<Right>', lambda event: self.move(inc=1))
        # use the lambda function to play the corresponding sound directly
        self.bind('<Return>', lambda event: playsound(self.soundlist(self.x)))

    # function to change to next/previous image
    def move(self, inc):
        self.x += inc
        if self.x >= len(self.imagelist):  # index out of range, start from 0
            self.x = 0
        elif self.x < 0:  # index out of range, start from last index
            self.x = len(self.imagelist) - 1
        # instead of assigning a image to an x value rather use x as an index for the list we created
        self.img_container.config(image=self.imagelist[self.x])


app = SlidshowApp()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.mainloop()
```

---

**In terms of the problem with `playsound()`**

Maby it is better to use a more well maintained library like pygame which might already be preinstalled on your raspberry pi. But consider that this needs to use the standard audio output.

This [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7088/playing-audio-files-with-python) shows how to use it and discusses alternatives.

So after checking if pygame is installed and updating it you can import the mixer object from pygame like `from pygame import mixer`. Then change the part in my script, where the sound paths are loaded into a list to this:

```py
# also glob all the sound paths (make sure the sounds are in the same order as the pictures!)
mixer.init()
for s_path in glob('/usr/share/scratch/Media/Sounds/Instruments/*.mp3'):
    self.soundlist.append(mixer.Sound(s_path))
```

Then change the binding for the sound back to `self.bind('<Return>', lambda event: self.sound4image())` and write the function as method of the class like this:

```py
# funbction to play the sound
def sound4image(self):
    mixer.Sound.play(self.soundlist[self.x])
    mixer.music.stop()
```